# iron-ajax on-response doesnt recognize dart reflected method

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

My ajax is defined as:

```
<iron-ajax id="myAjaxId" auto
     url="http://localhost:8088/test_server/v1/users/35"
     handle-as="json"
     on-response="{{handleResponse}}" ></iron-ajax>
```

and in my dart i say:

```
@reflectable
void handleResponse ( e, Map data ){
    print("hand response fired");
    f_name = data["f_name"];
    l_name = data["l_name"];
    id = data["id"];
}
```

not only does it not fire the print statement, but in the Chromium console, when it is run, it says:

```
[my-ajax-fetcher::_createEventHandler]: listener method `{{handleResponse}}` not defined
```

I was looking up some other examples and noticed @reflectable is the tag i should be applying.

I was also trying to look up what the target signature needs to look like, and didnt see anything.

Comment: Maybe the number or types of the parameters don't fit. Try instead `void handleResponse ({ e, data, f, g, h} ){` and if it works this way try to track down what exact signature it expects.

Comment: This doesnt cause the print statement to fire either.

Comment: And you also still get the error message? When you add a button and a click handler to the same component, does that work?

Comment: Still same error for it not being defined yes.  Ill add a button quick and test it with on-tap.  On Tap Still causes it to fire a Not defined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `{{}}` for event handlers in Polymer 1.x just `on-response="handleResponse"`

Comment: oh right.  Some functions now require curly-braces, other functions done.  Boggles my mind.

Comment: The function signature is a `CustomEventWrapper` and a `IronRequest` though, right now im investigating where the response json would be

Comment: Attribute and property bindings need `{{}}` but event bindings don't because there only function names are supported anyway. Property binding allows some kind of expressions.